# Dividing a sprinkler zone into two zones

Tags: sprinkler-system

I need to split an existing sprinkler zone into two zones. The issue I have is I cannot remove the valve that currently controls to flow. So, I want to have the system turn on both the original valve and one of the new.

For example. Current zone 5 becomes zones 5 and 6. When the controller kicks on zone 5 or 6, the original valve also opens.

All I can come up with is using 2 relays to make an logical OR circuit.

I am wondering what the best way to wire this up would be?

Comment: If you can't remove the current Zone 5 valve, can you make it always open?  Why does it ever need to be off?

Comment: Maybe, but it will not be easy. Keeping the valve open with power seems wrong, and I would think it would not last. I really though there would be a simple circuit to do this...

Comment: Some valves have a manual open as a backup/alternative to using a controller, or so they can be left partially open over winter.  Thought I'd ask.  If your controller has a Master Valve/Pump On circuit you could wire that to Zone 5 if you've got the spare wires running from the controller to the valve box.  It'd be open while Zones 1-4 were on as well, but that wouldn't matter.  If you just wired the new zones to run in parallel with Zone 5, then turning either on would turn both on.  Solving that in a trivial, water proof way...  Not sure.

Comment: Can the system simply operate two valves at once? If so, program the original to open in addition to either new zone. If instead you build a relay logic gate, I would propose a XOR gate (exclusive OR). The idea being to prevent the original valve from being on if *both* new valves also are for some reason. The intention is to prevent the system from driving more than two solenoids.

Answer (score 1):

My controller cannot operate two valves at the same time, but based on the comments from Scivitri, I looked around online and found a video that shows my RainBird valves can.

I have RainBird HV100 valves, and turning the solenoid counter-clockwise 90 degrees opens the valve. It is working like a charm!

I still want to research making a XOR circuit (Thank you JYelton) if I cannot get in and remove the valve, but for now I am up and running.

Thanks you all.